# CMP in assembly language

Tags: loops, assembly, cmp

So I have this line of code:

```
LOOP CMP Y, #0
BEQ DONE - When it is equal go to DONE.
ADD X, #1 - add decimal constant 1 to x.
SUB Y, #1 - subtract decimal constant 1 from y
B LOOP - branch loop (start the loop again)
DONE ...
```

I just read that CMP means subtracting the operand from Rn (Y minus 0)
And that CMN means adding the operand to the Rn (0 + Y for example)

The first line (LOOP CMP Y, #0): I thought this just compares Y with the number 0. Is this true?

Comment: What CPU is this assembly for? Can you tag the question with it?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: No guarantee, but it looks 6800ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- `cmp` (at least in most assembly languages) does a subtraction. It sets the flags based on the result of that subtraction, but then throws away the result itself.

Comment: Is it a conditional? I don't understand the point of it since there is a BEQ on the next line. Does the flow of processing change when the CMP comes back 0? (0 minus 0).

Comment: The BEQ branches based on the state of the `eq` flag, which is set/cleared by the previous `cmp`. Without the cmp, the BEQ would react based on whatever previous instruction happened to affect the eq flag.